# What is the pseudocode for this recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, recurrence

2T(n-1) - 1  if n >1 
1.      Else 
What would be the pseudocode for this recurrence relation?
 I am not able to find out the program in which this recurrence relation would be applied .   As this relation is having negative term , and as per my knowledge we can not have negative term in recurrence relation .

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and avoid such question

Comment: hi @deepika the best question practice for stack community is to add some code which you have tried and not based on opinions

Answer (score 0):

Take any graph G. Clone it, yielding G'. Now merge G and G' together by merging some vertex v and v' from each graph into one vertex. The number of vertices in the graph after doing this n times -- iteratively, that is, applying this operation to the output graph repeatedly -- obeys the relation T(n) = 2*T(n-1) - 1.